# Show previous product category when entering subcategory with last level - Woocomerce

Tags: categories, woocommerce-offtopic

For example :

- A

  - A.a
  - A.b
  - A.c

    - A.c.1
    - A.c.2
    - A.c.3

Currently I am displaying the child product categories of the current parent product category. I want to show previous subcategories when entering subcategories with last level. Ex: When entering the A.c.1 category, the previous subcategories will be displayed: A.c.1, A.c.2, A.c.3. And when entering the A.a category, it will display A.a, A.b, A.c.
How do I correct that?

Comment: Use of "previous" is confusing to me; are you wanting to show the parent category's siblings, or the current category's siblings?

Can you please provide an example of what is currently displaying, and an example of what you would prefer to display?